# building many programs that are managed by a parent program, looking like it's just one program

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a launcher type program which will allow me to launch other programs I made... not sure how to go about that...

The launcher needs to start/show the children programs when their button is clicked and make it seem like it's one single program, they will have similar layouts. When the launcher window is moved around, the child moves around with it...

I was thinking about having the launcher start the other programs (java -jar) when the respective button was clicked and passing arguments to tell the child program where to position it's window so it looks like it's just one program, which would probably work until that point... but when the user clicks away from the window, it needs to hide together with the launcher, but next time the button for that program is clicked, it should just continue where it left off, show the window...

I hope I explained that well...

I just need some hints about what to look into...

Comment: If all the programs are Java, you can just make each "program" into separate packages (each with its own JAR file), and let the launcher create instances as if it's a single project.

Comment: You might be looking for the Service Loader framework which is now - in Java 9 - baked into the language.

Comment: @MouseEvent I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: @Jai you mean build the entire project, launcher and the other programs into one project, different packages, and then export each package as it's own jar?

Comment: @amaiKy You can have separate projects which are developed separately, then each project will export to separate JAR file. Thereafter, the main project can import these JAR files and use them, just like how you would use a 3rd party API. This makes it a lot easier for the launcher to control all the parts and to keep the style consistent.

Comment: @Jai true I'll try that. My main idea was to build the launcher and then build the rest of the projects without having to change the launcher itself, but that works. Thank you sir!